# Javascript functional lazy evaluation example explanation required

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Browsing [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com) and I come across http://streamjs.org/ which is an implementation of a lazy evaluated collection in Javascript.

One of the examples is this:

```
function ones() {  
    return new Stream( 1, ones );  
}  
function naturalNumbers() {  
    return new Stream(  
        // the natural numbers are the stream whose first element is 1...  
        1,  
        function () {  
            // and the rest are the natural numbers all incremented by one  
            // which is obtained by adding the stream of natural numbers...  
            // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...  
            // to the infinite stream of ones...  
            // 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...  
            // yielding...  
            // 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...  
            // which indeed are the REST of the natural numbers after one  
            return ones().add( naturalNumbers() );  
        }   
    );  
}  
naturalNumbers().take( 5 ).print(); // prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Perhaps it's too late at night and I'm missing the point, but I don't understand how this prints 1,2,3,4,5.  I would expect it to print 1,2,2,2,2 and die of infinitely deep recursion.  I understand how `ones` will print infinite 1.  I don't get how `naturalNumbers` works.

By my (evidently incorrect) logic, the `head` of the `Stream` returned by the first call to `naturalNumbers` will be 1, and the next element in the stream is evaluated as `ones().add( naturalNumbers() );` which is `ones().add(1)` followed by `ones().add( naturalNumbers() )` which will reeavulate to `1` and so on...

Would really appreciate it if someone would shed some light on this.

Comment: Where is the code for `Stream`?

Comment: It's on http://streamjs.org/ - that's where the example is from.

Comment: I have Oz at school, and this reminds me so much of Oz' list-solutions... :-/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
naturalNumbers[0] = 1 // by definition
naturalNumbers[1] = ones[0] + naturalNumbers[0] = 1 + 1 = 2
naturalNumbers[2] = ones[1] + naturalNumbers[1] = 1 + 2 = 3
naturalNumbers[3] = ones[2] + naturalNumbers[2] = 1 + 3 = 4
...
```

The crucial point is that `function() { return ones().add(naturalNumbers()) }` does not return an element, it returns a *stream*.  Subsequent elements are generated by that stream, a "summing" stream in this case.  Thus, unlike `ones()`, `naturalNumbers()` does not invoke itself directly.  Rather, it invokes itself indirectly -- mediated by the summing stream.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'll take this on :)

`ones` is the easy starting point. This function returns a `Stream` whose first value is `1`, and whose remaining values can be calulated by invoking the `ones` function itself. So any request for the 'rest' of `one`'s values will always start with `1`, ad infinitum.

The next thing to look at is the `take` function:

```
function (howmany) {
    if (this.empty()) {
        return this;
    }
    if (howmany == 0) {
        return new Stream;
    }
    var self = this;
    return new Stream(this.head(), function () {
        return self.tail().take(howmany - 1);
    });
}
```

So from the top to the bottom, if the `Stream` is empty then it doesn't matter how many items were requested as that request can't be fulfilled, so the `Stream` returns its (empty) self.

If we've requested no items, i.e. `howmany == 0`, then an empty `Stream` is returned, which itself will yield no items if asked.

Lastly is the fun part. A reference to the current `Stream` is locked into the function scope and a new `Stream` is returned. This new `Stream` is created with the same head as the current `Stream`, and whose tail is created by a function that will `take` one less item from the original `Stream`'s tail than the caller requested. So as the head is one item and the tail can generate `howmany-1` items, the caller will receive a new `Stream` with the potential to deliver the requested number of items.

The `naturalNumbers` are a bit more tricky.

The `naturalNumbers` function returns a `Stream` that has `1` as its head, and an inner function to generate its tail.

The inner function returns the result of calling the `add` method on the `ones` Stream, with the result of calling the `naturalNumbers` function. So we can guess that this involves 'pairing' two `Stream`s together in some way.

What does add look like? It's a function that is passed a `Stream`:

```
function (s) {
    return this.zip(function (x, y) {
        return x + y;
    }, s);
}
```

We can recognise the 'add' part as the inner function - it's adding two values together, so that makes sense. But what does `zip` do? `zip` is a function that takes a function and a `Stream` as parameters.

```
function (f, s) {
    if (this.empty()) {
        return s;
    }
    if (s.empty()) {
        return this;
    }
    var self = this;
    return new Stream(f(s.head(), this.head()), function () {
        return self.tail().zip(f, s.tail());
    });
}
```

So in the case of add, the function passed in was the 'add' (x+y) function, and the `Stream` was the `naturalNumbers` `Stream`.

What does `zip` do with these values? If the `Stream` itself is empty, the the 'other' `Stream` is returned. I guess this is because adding [] to [2,4,6,8,...] makes more sense to be [2,3,6,8,...] than anything else. i.e. the first Stream is treated as infinitely many `0` or `""`.

If the passed-in `Stream` is empty, then the same rule as above applies, just in reverse. i.e. adding [2,4,6,8,...] to [].

Now the fun part. After capturing a reference to itself, a new `Stream` is returned. This `Stream` is made up of a head value which is the 'add' function applied to the head elements of each `Stream` and a function that will apply the 'add' function to the tail of each `Stream` if required.

So in the case of `ones().add(naturalNumbers())`, this would result in a `Stream` whose head is `2`, as the 'add' function is called with `1` and `1` (the head element of both `ones` and `naturalNumbers` are both `1`). So if this new `Stream` is asked to be added to `ones`, then it will be `ones` head element (always `1`) added to the new `Stream`'s head element (now `2`), giving `3`.

The tail of this new `Stream` is a mechanism to deliver more 'adds' if required.

So what we are left with is basically a way of describing operations to be applied to head elements and the tail. Only when we come to ask for a particular number of items do we go through the machinery to generate those items.

So if you called `ones().take(9999999999999999999999999999999).print()` then it would take a lot of resources as the `print` function *needs* to have the value before it can print it - it necessarily causes this machinery to have to deliver that many `1`s. But `ones().take(9999999999999999999999999999999)` on its own is just a description of the head element `1` and a process to deliver the rest of the items, but only if asked for.

**But...** I could have got that completely wrong as it's late for me too and I've only just read the article ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just carry out the evaluations one term at a time:

```
ones
= { 1, ones }
= { 1, { 1, ones } }
= ...
= { 1, { 1, { 1, ... to infinity!

nat
= { 1, ones+nat }
= { 1, { 1, ones } + { 1, ones+nat } } = { 1, { 1+1, ones+ones+nat } }
= { 1, { 2, { 1, ones } + { 1, ones } + { 1, nat } } }
= ...
= { 1, { 2, { 3, ... and so on.
```

The "sieve" example at the botton of http://streamjs.org is even more mind-twisting, try it!